How to create a roundabout symbol
I have a point dataset that represents the centres of a painted roundabout as per the image below.
I would like to create a symbol in ArcGIS Pro that looks similar. The solid circle in the centre is the easy bit but I can't figure out which effects to use on a stroke symbol to add the curved arrow around the point. If I can figure out how to create one, the other two will just be drawn with different angles/offsets.
Can anyone shed some light on this? Again this is a point dataset and this just needs to be represented graphically so I am not looking to create new features to achieve this.
TIA

Why not using an SVG point symbol ? You can use an existing one (some exemple https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:SVG_mandatory_road_signs_%E2%80%93_roundabout) or create your own...

I could do that but I was curious to know whether this could be achieved with the available symbol layers & corresponding symbol effects.

To do it with the symbol layer I would use a point symbol layer for the arrow ("ArcGIS 2D" style has curved arrow symbol for exemple) rather than stroke with effect...

Esri tend to use fonts even for picture markers, in the former ArcMap world they had styles https://community.esri.com/t5/mapping-questions/intersection-symbology-traffic-light-stop-light/td-p/297044

I was able to create this symbol:

It is composed of 5 layers:

The stroke and markers all utilise the buffer and dash effect. The stroke had a dash and buffer size of 12

Whilst the triangles had a dash of 12 and some judicious tweaking of the offset XY, one such triangle is shown below

Et voila! Here is a link to a style file I created for it, which you can tweak as needed.

You're a legend! Thank you for your detailed explanation and the style file, it's much appreciated.
